# Add extra fields in ManyToMany relationship Symfony 6

Tags: symfony, many-to-many

Hi so i created a many to many relationship between 2 entities named client and offre

here is my entity client :

```
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Offre::class, inversedBy: 'clients')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name:"CLIENTID", referencedColumnName:"clientid")]
#[ORM\InverseJoinColumn(name: "OFFREID", referencedColumnName: "offreid")]
#[ORM\JoinTable(name: "clients_offre")] 
private Collection $offres;
```

here is my entity offre

```
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: client::class, mappedBy: 'offres')]
private Collection $clients;
```

As planned it created me a table named clients_offre with CLIENTID and OFFREID.

Now i want to add a commentaire field in this table but this field has no referencedColumnName so i don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance to those who take the time to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a direct relationship between two entities with extra columns.

You need to create a new Entity that will be the intermediary between `Client` and `Offre`.

Your new entity could be called `ClientOffre` and will be related to both `Client` and `Offre` with two **OneToMany** and two **ManyToOne**.

```
public class ClientOffre {
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Client::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name:"client_id", referencedColumnName:"id")]
    private $client;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Offre::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name:"offre_id", referencedColumnName:"id")]
    private $offre;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $comment = null;
}
```

And your current entity will have a OneToMany relationship with this new entity:

```
public class Client {
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: ClientOffre::class, mappedBy: "client")]
    private Collection $clientOffres;
}

public class Offre {
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: ClientOffre::class, mappedBy: "offre")]
    private Collection $clientOffres;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ! if anyone does not understand how it works, i found this video https://www.facebook.com/garyclarketech/videos/doctrine-many-to-many-relationship-with-extra-fields-columns-learn-symfony-doctr/394215878493323/